# What does the "and" keyword do in this statement?

Tags: python-3.x

(changed title thanks to @bb1950328)

```
from pycaw.pycaw import AudioUtilities
def main():
    sessions = AudioUtilities.GetAllSessions()
    for session in sessions:
        volume = session.SimpleAudioVolume
        if session.Process and session.Process.name() == "chrome.exe":
            volume.SetMute(0, None)
        else:
            volume.SetMute(1, None)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This one of the examples of pycaw.(https://github.com/AndreMiras/pycaw/blob/develop/examples/volume_by_process_example.py)

This expression confuses me:

```
session.Process and session.Process.name()
```

Then I tried something:

```
>>> from pycaw.pycaw import AudioUtilities
>>> sessions = AudioUtilities.GetAllSessions()
>>> for session in sessions:
...     print(session.Process and session.Process.name())
...
None
firefox.exe
wemeetapp.exe
>>> for session in sessions:
...     print(session.Process)
...
None
psutil.Process(pid=4576, name='firefox.exe', status='running', started='09:55:56')
psutil.Process(pid=4560, name='wemeetapp.exe', status='running', started='09:51:20')
>>> for session in sessions:
...     print(session.Process.name())
...
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
```

This is how python describe "and" in its documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not) : `if x is false, then x, else y`
But my result is like:`x is false, then abc`.

I get

```
None
firefox.exe
wemeetapp.exe
```

for `session.Process and session.Process.name()` and

```
None
psutil.Process(pid=4576, name='firefox.exe', status='running', started='09:55:56')
psutil.Process(pid=4560, name='wemeetapp.exe', status='running', started='09:51:20')
```

for `session.Process` only.

I think the thing that makes this happen may not be "and", but something else.

Comment: I know nothing about Python, but lots of languages have "short circuiting" boolean expressions. At the first "false" the evaluation stops.  Also, some languages let you test implicitly for a variable being null by writing "if object_variable" - So what I think it's saying is "if there is a non-null session.Process, then check one of its properties" - If you check a property of a null object, it will throw an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `and` is a guard for the situation when `session.Process` is `None`; in that case, it shouldn't try to do `.name()` on it, because that would fail

It only tries to retrieve the name of the processes that are not `None`

Comment: So... On the first time of loop, [session.Process] is None, so trying to get [session.Process.name()] will cause an error and stops the loop. If we manage to skip the first time of loop, I'll get "firefox.exe wemeetapp.exe", right?

Comment: Yeah; the way `and` works, it won't try to get the second value if the first value determines the answer. You can test that by defining functions that do a `print()` before returning `True` or `False` and playing with the various combinations to see when they get called and when they don't

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
>>> from pycaw.pycaw import AudioUtilities
>>> sessions = AudioUtilities.GetAllSessions()
>>> i=1
>>> for session in sessions:
...     if i==1:
...             pass
...     else:
...             print(session.Process.name())
...     i=i+1
...
firefox.exe
wemeetapp.exe
```

Huge thanks to sabik!